# How to make subpage with new URL for every post automaticly [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, posts

I have an infinitely scrolling home page that gets posts from a MySQL database with fetch requests and inserts them with javascript.

```
for(var a = 0; a < reslength; a++){
        html += `<div class="post">`;
            html += `<div class="meta">`;
                html += `<div class="op">` + results[a].username + `</div>`;
                html += `<div class="date">` + results[a].time + `</div>`;
            html += `</div>`;
        html += `<h2 class="post-title">` + results[a].title + `</h2>`;
        html += `<div class="content">`;
            html += `<p class="post-content">` + results[a].content + `</p>`;
        html += `</div>`;

        html += `<div class="attachment-container">...</div></div>`;
        };
        document.querySelector('.container').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(html)));
    }
```

How would I make it so that if you click on the posts it would serve a dedicated page for the post with its own custom URL (the plan is to have replies and stats there).

I'm guessing I need to already have an URL prepared to have it wrapped around the JS? How do you do this automatically for every post?

Answer (score 1):

With whatever you are using to host the site, you would handle requests in one function and read the post ID from information passed in the request. You didn't mention the backend web framework you were using, other than that it was NodeJS-based, but this article will explain how you could do it with params and queries in ExpressJS:

https://coursework.vschool.io/express-params-and-query/

Then, to customize the served content, you can use a templating engine like [Pug](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) to customize the returned content based on the given post.